# How to designate personal template as default in PowerPoint Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I would like to designate MyFile.potx as the default PowerPoint template. How do I do this? I am using the version that comes with Office 365, and the instructions I found online for other PowerPoint versions (2013, 2016) don't seem to work. I am using Windows 10 and am not an administrator of the Office 365 setup, just a user.

For example, when creating a New presentation, there is no 'Personal' or 'Custom' choice in my version of PowerPoint:

[image]

(Here is what I see when I follow @harrymc's suggestion in his answer. It is the bottom of the dropdown menu under the left pane under Design. 'Browse for Themes' is at the end.)
[image]

Comment: After you have added the template, perhaps you have missed the last step in [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-a-personal-template-to-create-a-new-powerpoint-presentation-71262c90-1447-4109-90f3-eb84f9d06c98).

Comment: I updated my question to show that I don't have the 'Personal' or 'Custom' option available in the version of PowerPoint that comes with Office 365.

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes. Added that info to question.

Comment: Did you copy your template (.potx) file to the folder at: `C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\Custom Office Templates`?

Comment: Yes (I had to create the folder because the regular Documents folder is under a OneDrive backup folder).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When creating a New presentation, there is no 'Personal' or 'Custom' choice in my version of PowerPoint

This was the problem that brought me to this question. Using PowerPoint for Office 365, I had a provided `potx` file and placed it correctly into `C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\Custom Office Templates\`, but could not get the option for Personal templates to show where the documentation and screenshots in this thread said it should be showing.

The fix was to open the template file itself and [re-save it with my Office 365 version of PowerPoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-save-a-powerpoint-template-ee4429ad-2a74-4100-82f7-50f8169c8aca#OfficeVersion=Windows). The template was likely created with a previous version of PowerPoint.

After re-saving and making sure the newly saved version is in the `Custom Office Templates` folder, I was able to see a Personal section when creating a New file.

Answer (score 2):

I am using a recent (2023) version of PowerPoint for 365 and none of the above answers worked for me.

Version (File -> Account -> About Powerpoint):

`Microsoft® PowerPoint® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2210 Build 16.0.15726.20188) 64-bit`

[The instructions found here worked for me (from among the millions of out-of-date "official" Microsoft answers to this question).](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/where-are-my-custom-templates-88ed77ca-df34-49e9-9087-3f01ae296e6e)

1. Open a powerpoint that has you theme applied.
2. Press `Alt+Q` or click in the search bar and type `Save Current Theme`, then click the top result.
3. Navigate to the newly designated themes folder located at `%appdata%\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes` (paste this into the explorer navigation bar).
4. Restart powerpoint

Comment: This addresses the new theme format from `.potx` to `.thmx` Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft
[documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-a-personal-template-to-create-a-new-powerpoint-presentation-71262c90-1447-4109-90f3-eb84f9d06c98)
seems to be incomplete.

To set your template as a default option:

- Copy the template (.potx) file to the Templates folder at:

  ```
  C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\Custom Office Templates\
  ```
- Open the presentation
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all slides
- On the ribbon, position to the Design pane
- Click the lower down-arrow icon on the right of the leftmost pane
- You should see your theme under "Custom"
- Right-click the theme and select "Set as Default Theme"

[image]

Comment: I have replaced your image by one where is indicated in red the down-arrow to press.

Comment: I updated the 2nd screenshot to show the full list of options I get under 'Design'. I can 'Browse for Theme' to find MyFile.potx but don't have the right click option to set it as the default. Instead when I right click on MyFile.potx, I get standard Windows options for files (Rename, Delete, etc). And after I select MyFile.potx under 'Browse', then subsequently open a New presentation, I don't have MyFile.potx as an option. I just get the same screenshot #1 where I can choose only online themes.

Answer (score 1):

Open your .potx file in powerpoint.  File--->Open

Save as Template ---> File --> Save as Template (Alternatively you can copy paste the .potx file into the Templates folder

Navigate to Design on the menu and click the arrow below the design samples.

In the resulting window, you will see the design of your template.

At the bottom of the window, you will see a Save Current Theme.  Select your template design and Save Current Theme.  Give it a name and save it into the themes folder.

Now select your custom design theme.  (Design menu --> bottom arrow) Right click and select default theme.

Every time you start a new presentation, the design theme in your potx file will default

Answer (score 0):

Start PPT, let it create a new presentation (anything, even Blank will do).

Go to the Design tab, open the gallery of designs, find the one you want to use, right-click it and choose "Set as Default Theme".

Now when you start PPT or do File | New, your new Default Theme should be the first option you see.

Comment: When creating a 'New' presentation, I do not seem to be able to search for designs based on a *.potx file that I have created (see the screenshot that I just added). The only design choices seem to only be built-in designs that came with the version of PowerPoint that comes with Office 365.

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to start a new presentation first, then apply a template to it. If you don't want to use one of the supplied ones, choose "Browse for Themes" from the bottom of the template gallery. That'll let you choose POTX files as well.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to set MyFile.potx as the default so I do not have to browse for it?

Comment: You only have to browse for it once.  Please do TRY what I've suggested; then if it's not working as expected, follow up here.

Comment: See screenshot #2: as you indicated, I can browse for themes. But after I've browsed for MyFile.potx, when I subsequently open a New presentation, MyFile.potx is not an option or the default; I just get the choices shown in screenshot #1. So it doesn't seem to remember MyFile.potx as a default.